# Alias one set of Subdomains to another

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I have to domains that I want to effectively mirror one another on select subdomains. Let's say they are pirates.com and ninjas.com and i want ninjas to mirror the content on pirates.

When I visit `foo.ninjas.com` I want to see the content on `foo.pirates.com`. Due to app restrictions I need to do this in DNS for an undefined number of subdomains. I was under the impression i could do this with a CNAME, but it appears that setting a CNAME for * subdomain of the `ninjas.com` domain to point to `pirates.com` will make any subdomain of ninjas.com point at pirates.com instead of the associated subdomain. I.e. `foo.ninjas.com` would reference `pirates.com` instead of `foo.pirates.com`.

Is there a way to do this using DNS? Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 1):

DNS is only one part of the story. The web server must be aware of the domain names that you intend to use. So you will have to set up the names in the web server as well (e.g. using Apache's `ServerAlias` directive.

Comment: So you're saying that the CNAME part should be working correctly that `foo.ninjas.com` should be pointed at `foo.pirates.com` but i have to change my server config on pirates?

Comment: Correct. Unless the web server knows what to do with `foo.ninjas.com` then it will just serve the default virtual host, which is probably a test page.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the DNS server, and if it uses zonefiles, you can make both domains use the same zonefile.

An example for bind:

```
zone "ninjas.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "master/ninjas.com.zone";
};

zone "pirates.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "master/ninjas.com.zone";
};
```

I use this technique to make ~2500 domainnames look exactly the same :)